# How to compute thermodynamic magnitudes with the Green's function?

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, path-integral, greens-functions

I'm studying the SYK model and there seems two equivalent approaches for solving it. One is the diagrammatic expansion in the large $N$ limit, where we get self-consistent equations (in imaginary time)

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
G(i\omega)=\frac{1}{i\omega-\Sigma(i\omega)} && \Sigma(\tau)=J^2G(\tau)^3
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

The other approach involves solving the path integral in order to obtain the generating functional $\mathcal{Z}$. It is my understanding that diagrammatic and path integral approaches should be equal, in the end. However, I only know how to derive thermodynamic magnitudes with the partition function. we can calculate the free energy $F$ as an expansion in the euclidean action and once we know $F$ it's just using regular statistical mechanics to get the internal energy $U$, the specific heat $c_V$, etc.

How do we connect Green's functions (in imaginary or real time, I don't know yet) to thermodynamic magnitudes?

Answer (score 1):

In the SYK model one can write down the path integral form of the (disorder averaged) partition function $\langle Z\rangle_J$ and using some tricks find an action in terms of two bi-local fields $\widetilde{G}(\tau,\tau')$ and $\widetilde{\Sigma}(\tau,\tau')$. I think this procedure is best explained in the paper [Ads$_2$ holography and the SYK model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.08482.pdf) by Gábor Sárosi.

What is so interesting about this form of the action is that in the large $N$ limit the theory becomes classical and one can thus use EFT tools. When finding the the extrema of this action using EFT one finds the Schwinger-Dyson equations (self-consistency equations you state). In the saddle point of the action $\widetilde{G}(\tau,\tau')$ and $\widetilde{\Sigma}(\tau,\tau')$ correspond directly to the two-point function and the self-energy of the model. This connects the Green's functions to the thermodynamics of the model since you can write $\langle Z\rangle_J=e^{-NI[G,\Sigma]}$.

Answer (score 0):

Free energy can be computed using perturbative diagrammatic approach by summing over **all the connected** bubble diagrams in the theory. Basically, this is due to the fact that the path integral, $\mathcal Z$, is sum over **all** the bubble diagrams (connected as well as disconnected), and a simple argument shows that the exponential of the sum over connected diagrams in fact generates all these diagrams (I think this is discussed somewhere in Weinberg's QFT Vol. 2. I am sorry I don't immediately have access to the book to be able to provide the exact reference, I will update the post once I get access to the book).

When you carefully sum over all the diagrams, then you will typically end up with diagrams involving exact propagators (for example $G(\tau)$ in SYK model) and the expression will be same as the *path integral approach* expression that you mentioned in your question. In context of SYK model and the SYK-like tensor models this is discussed in [Witten's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.09758).